# Importing CSV to MySQL table returns an error #1148

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I am trying to import with DirectAdmin, when I selected CSV without using LOAD DATA - I got the error "Invalid field count in CSV input on line 1."

When I tried with LOAD DATA I got the following error: "#1148 - The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version."

The CSV was created in MS Access from MS Access database.

Here are the first 2 rows:

```
"product_id","vendor_id"," product_parent_id","product_sku","product_s_desc ","product_desc","product_thumb_image ","product_full_image","product_publish","product_weight","product_weight_uom ","product_length ","product_width","product_height ","product_lwh_uom ","disp_order","price","sale","product_url ","product_in_stock","product_available_date","product_availability ","product_special ","product_discount_id ","ship_code_id ","cdate ","mdate ","product_name ","product_sales ","attribute ","custom_attribute ","product_tax_id ","product_unit ","product_packaging ","child_options ","quantity_options ","child_option_ids ","product_order_levels "
41,2,0,1,,,"resized/Krug-Rose-Champagne-lg.jpg","Krug-Rose-Champagne-lg.jpg","Y","750.0000","grams","4.0000","4.0000",14,,14,3516,0,,,1296518400,,"N",0,"NULL ",1296574622,1297953843,"קרוג רוזה",0,,,2,"piece ",65537,"N,N,N,N,N,Y,20%,10%, ","none,0,0,1 ",,"0,0 "
```

Comment: Maybe it's the `קרוג רוזה",`  which *seems* to have a missing double quote? (Not sure. Hard to tell because of the Left-To-Right)

Comment: There are other quote irregularities too... e.g. "2,

Comment: I checked the quotes, even removed all the quotes from the file, but that didn't help.

Comment: @Pekka: Many DB's store RTL text, this one seems to be missing double quote only because there is an RTL issue, the CSV file was generated by Access, and edited in Libre Office, I don't think there's a mistake with the double quotes.

Comment: We tried everything, called 2 people who claimed to be experts and they didn't have a clue. Eventualy we used EMS Data Import for MySQL  a very usefull tool.

Answer (score 5):

From mysql command line pass the following parameter:

```
mysql -u username -p dbname --local-infile
```

Instead of using: `load data infile`, use: `load data local infile` and it should perform the import.

By default, mysql does not enable `load data local` as per the the security concerns defined here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data-local.html

> If LOAD DATA LOCAL is disabled, either in the server or the client, a
>   client that attempts to issue such a statement receives the following
>   error message:
>
> ERROR 1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Comment: I am still getting error 1148, even with `--local-infile` specified, MySQL 5.5