# using flags in Python MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I want to use the python MySQLdb to access a remote MySQL server with --local-infile flag in order to be able to load data from a local file. (as mentioned in this question [Importing CSV to MySQL table returns an error #1148](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133501/importing-csv-to-mysql-table-returns-an-error-1148))

I use

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", port=3307, user="someuser", passwd="password", db="sql_db")
```

to create a database connection. How do I mimic `mysql -u username -p dbname --local-infile` using MySQLdb

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late for the initial question, but if someone comes here looking for the same you can do this:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="",
    allow_local_infile=True,
)
```

Here you can check the docs for aditional flags: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html

If you want to set it as a DB config rather than in the connection, you can do it like this:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="",
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

try:
    command = "SET GLOBAL local_infile = 'ON';"
    mycursor.execute(command)
except mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your DB configurations in to a local file, and then read it when using.

config.ini

```
[MySQL]
host=192.168.20.28
user=root
password=123456
db_name=ovp_global
charset=utf8
```

py code:

```
import MySQLdb
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.readfp(open("config.ini", "r"))


def get_connection():
    host = config.get('MySQL', 'host')
    user = config.get('MySQL', 'user')
    passwd = config.get('MySQL', 'password')
    db = config.get('MySQL', 'db_name')
    charset = config.get('MySQL', 'charset')

    return MySQLdb.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=passwd, db=db, charset=charset)
```

Comment: Does the MySQLdb.connect() support flags? Can I set local-infile=1 in the config and pass that in?